# Windows app development using windows 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, windows

Can I develop a Windows Phone & store apps on both using Visual Studio 2012. Although it is recommended to use Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop apps for wither but you will not be able to make universal. Why would you want to do that when you can download the VS2013 Express version and develop proper 8.1 universal apps?